# Executing a shell script within docker with RUN command

Tags: bash, shell, docker, dockerfile

New to dockers, so please bear with me.

My Dockerfile contains an ENTRYPOINT:

```
ENV MONGOD_START "mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log --logappend --smallfiles"
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "$MONGOD_START"]
```

I have a shell script add an entry to database through python script, and starts the server.

The script **startApp.sh**

```
chmod +x /addAddress.py
python /addAddress.py $1
cd /myapp/webapp 
grunt serve --force
```

Now, all the below RUN commands are unsuccessful in executing this script.

```
sudo docker run -it --privileged myApp -C /bin/bash && /myApp/webapp/startApp.sh loc

sudo docker run -it --privileged myApp /myApp/webapp/startApp.sh loc
```

The docker log of container is

```
"about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections. forked process: 7 child process started successfully, parent exiting "
```

Also, the startApp.sh executes fine when I open a bash prompt in docker and run it.

I am unable to figure out what wrong I am doing, help please.

Comment: What's the output of `docker logs <container>`  ? Have you tried launching the container with just bash instead of startApp.sh and then executing startApp.sh from your bash prompt?

Comment: sudo docker ps doesn't show this as a running container. So can't fetch the logs.

When trying to launch a bash and executing startApp.sh it runs fine and gives me the expected output.

Comment: Okay, the container which exited without any further response has the following log - "about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 7
child process started successfully, parent exiting
"

Comment: Please don't post additional info in comments; add this info to the question by [edit] ing it instead.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out Frank, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to create an **entrypoint.sh** file:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Initialize start DB command
# Pick from env variable MONGOD_START if it exists
# else use the default value provided in quotes
START_DB=${MONGOD_START:-"mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log --logappend --smallfiles"}

# This will start your DB in background
${START_DB} &

# Go to startApp directory and execute commands
`chmod +x /addAddress.py;python /addAddress.py $1; \
               cd /myapp/webapp ;grunt serve --force`
```

Then modify your Dockerfile by removing the last line and replacing it with following 3 lines:

```
COPY entrypoint.sh /

RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Then rebuild your container image using

```
docker build -t NAME:TAG .
```

Now you run following command to verify if **ENTRYPOINT** is */entrypoint.sh*

```
docker inspect NAME:TAG | less
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess (and I might be wrong, since I'm neither a MongoDB nor a Docker expert) that your combination of `mongod --fork` and `/bin/sh -c` is the culprit.

What you're essentially executing is this:

`/bin/sh -c mongod --fork ...`

which

- executes a shell
- this shell executes a single command and waits for it to finish
- this command launches MongoDB in daemon mode
- MongoDB forks and *immediately exits*

The easiest fix is probably to just use

```
 CMD ["mongod"]
```

like the [official MongoDB Docker](https://github.com/dockerfile/mongodb/blob/master/Dockerfile) does.

Comment: Frank, I need the --fork because while building the docker. There are certain initial data that I need to populate into MongoDB. It has to run in a separate shell.

Comment: I tried your approach too, without using fork. It doesn't even complete execution of the mongod and thus never reaches the script.